# The picture I selected with the help of the button I defined in the fragment is not registered to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, fragment, storage

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var firestore: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var storage: FirebaseStorage

private lateinit var activityResultLauncher : ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
private lateinit var permissionLauncher : ActivityResultLauncher<String>
var selectedPicture : Uri? = null

private var _binding: FragmentProfileBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    auth = Firebase.auth
    firestore = Firebase.firestore
    storage = Firebase.storage

    registerLauncher()
}


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root

    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment)
    binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    imageUpload.setOnClickListener {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(requireActivity(),android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                Snackbar.make(view,"Galeriye erişmek için izin vermeniz gerekmektedir.",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("İzin Ver"){
                    permissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                }.show()
            }else{
                permissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            }
        }else{
            val intentToGallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            activityResultLauncher.launch(intentToGallery)
        }

        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
        val imageName = "$uuid.jpg"

        val reference = storage.reference
        val imageReference = reference.child("images").child(imageName)

        if (selectedPicture!=null){
            imageReference.putFile(selectedPicture!!).addOnSuccessListener {
                val uploadPictureReference = storage.reference.child("images").child(imageName)
                uploadPictureReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    val downloadUrl = it.toString()

                    val profileMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
                    profileMap.put("downloadUrl",downloadUrl)

                    firestore.collection("Profile").add(profileMap).addOnSuccessListener {
                        
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),it.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }

            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),it.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun registerLauncher(){
    activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            val intentFromResult = result.data
            if (intentFromResult !=null){
                selectedPicture = intentFromResult.data
                selectedPicture?.let {
                    binding.selectImage.setImageURI(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()){result->
        if (result){
            val intentToGallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            activityResultLauncher.launch(intentToGallery)
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Galeriye Erişim İçin İzin Gereklidir.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

The codes written here belong to the fragment I created the profile page for.

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage by clicking the button with imageUpload id. However, it is not saved to the Storage and the photo I uploaded disappears when I click on a different page.

Do I need to add the codes somewhere other than OnViewCreated?

Also, when I assign an onClick method to a button, image or something else, I cannot call it with the fun method. For example, let uploadImage be the onClick function, not the button's id. I can't define it as 'fun uploadImage' anywhere in the fragment, why?

Comment: There are no calls to any of the Firebase the `.put...`  methods that upload data, which makes it hard to understand what the problem is. Can you show what you tried to implement the upload of the file already, based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?

Comment: I edited the code and my problem still persists.

Comment: Thanks that helps. But we're still missing debug information here, which makes it less likely we can spot what happens. If you put breakpoints on `if (selectedPicture!=null){`, `imageReference.putFile(selectedPicture!!)`, and on the first line inside its success and failure handler, and then run the code in a debugger, does it reach any of these lines? Are the values of each variable what you expect them to be?

Comment: When I upload the photo and change the page, it says these in the debug section.

V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
W/ect.sonarsyste: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)